# Null result statement from other class

Tags: java, mysql, sqlite, jdbc, resultset

The result set that I'm trying to retrieve from another class returns null, even though the query works.I'm trying to initialize my object based on the records kept in databases,which means if there is initially a record in sqlite,I retrieve the one with latest date.Else,I try to retrieve the earliest one from mysql database. The code that is supposed to retrieve result set from mysql database is like this:

```
   public ResultSet lowestDate() throws SQLException {
    ResultSet rs1 = null;
    String resultQuery = "SELECT * FROM alarm ORDER BY `timestamp` ASC LIMIT 1";
    rs1 = stmt.executeQuery(resultQuery);
    return rs1;
}
```

Statement is initialized globally.And I call this in another class like this:

```
public void setLastAlarm() throws SQLException, ParseException {
    String liteQuery = "SELECT * FROM alarm_entries ORDER BY date(`timestamp`) DESC LIMIT 1";
    conn.connectLite();
    Connection getCon = conn.getLiteConnection();
    try {
        stmt = getCon.createStatement();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(liteQuery);
        if (rs.next()) {
            //while (rs.next()) {
            nuDate = rs.getString("timestamp");
            newDate = format.parse(nuDate);
            lastAlarm.setBacklogId(rs.getBytes("backlog_id"));
            lastAlarm.setTimestamp(newDate);
            //}
        }
        else{
            rsq=mysqlConnection.lowestDate();
            lastAlarm.setTimestamp(format.parse(rsq.getString("timestamp")));
            lastAlarm.setBacklogId(rsq.getBytes("backlog_id"));
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void run() {
    try {
        setLastAlarm();
```

Answer (score 0):

You never call `ResultSet#next()` on the result set being returned from the `lowestDate()` helper method.  Hence, the cursor is never being advanced to the first (and only) record in the result set.  But I think it is a bad idea to factor your JDBC code in this way.  Instead, just inline your two queries like this:

```
try {
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(liteQuery);
    if (rs.next()) {
        nuDate = rs.getString("timestamp");
        newDate = format.parse(nuDate);
        lastAlarm.setBacklogId(rs.getBytes("backlog_id"));
        lastAlarm.setTimestamp(newDate);
    }
    else {
        String resultQuery = "SELECT * FROM alarm ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 1";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(resultQuery);
        if (rs.next()) {
            String ts = rs.getString("timestamp");
            lastAlarm.setTimestamp(format.parse(ts));
            lastAlarm.setBacklogId(rs.getBytes("backlog_id"));
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: It did not work, it's just jumping over the whole thing, why is this happening?When I query the same query it returns data

Comment: Then perhaps your first query is never coming up empty.  Have you checked the actual data in your tables?

Comment: Yeah what I meant was I checked the data in tables and query is working there

Comment: You're going to have to step through your code with a debugger.  I have pointed out several problems, but I don't see anything wrong with the code itself in my answer.